# SQL Server 2008 R2 running sum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like below.

`row_no` and `product` are PK.

```
+--------+---------+-------+-----+---------------+---------+
| row_no | Product | value | qoh | prev_week_qty | cum_qty |
+--------+---------+-------+-----+---------------+---------+
| 1      | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 2      | pr:1    | 201   | 101 | NULL          | 100     |
| 3      | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 4      | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 5      | pr:1    | 183   | 101 | NULL          | -18     |
| 6      | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 7      | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 8      | pr:1    | 149   | 101 | NULL          | -34     |
| 9      | pr:1    | 131   | 101 | NULL          | -18     |
| 10     | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 11     | pr:1    | 113   | 101 | NULL          | -18     |
| 12     | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NUll    |
| 13     | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NUll    |
| 14     | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NUll    |
| 17     | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
+--------+---------+-------+-----+---------------+---------+
```

Is there any way to implement this without usig cusrsor?

**Logic:**  Value = qoh + cum_qty + prev_week_qty

For ex:

- For row_no=1, value = qoh+prev_week_qty+cum_qty.
- For row_no=2, qoh = (row_no = 1.value), then  qoh+ prev_week_qty+cum_qty
- For row_no=3, qoh = (row_no = 2.value), then  qoh+ prev_week_qty+cum_qty

Expected output:

```
+--------+---------+-------+-----+---------------+---------+
| row_no | Product | value | qoh | prev_week_qty | cum_qty |
+--------+---------+-------+-----+---------------+---------+
| 1      | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 2      | pr:1    | 201   | 101 | NULL          | 100     |
| 3      | pr:1    | 201   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 4      | pr:1    | 201   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 5      | pr:1    | 183   | 101 | NULL          | -18     |
| 6      | pr:1    | 183   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 7      | pr:1    | 183   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 8      | pr:1    | 149   | 101 | NULL          | -34     |
| 9      | pr:1    | 131   | 101 | NULL          | -18     |
| 10     | pr:1    | 131   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
| 11     | pr:1    | 113   | 101 | NULL          | -18     |
| 12     | pr:1    | 113   | 101 | NULL          | NUll    |
| 13     | pr:1    | 113   | 101 | NULL          | NUll    |
| 14     | pr:1    | 113   | 101 | NULL          | NUll    |
| 17     | pr:1    | 101   | 101 | NULL          | NULL    |
+--------+---------+-------+-----+---------------+---------+
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I didnt get that logic to calculate `Value` column

Comment: @Prdp Edited the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SQL SERVER 2012+` you can use `SUM()OVER(ORDER BY)` trick unfortunately you are using older version. Try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable A
       CROSS apply (SELECT Sum(Isnull([cum_qty], 0)
                               + Isnull(prev_week_qty, 0) + CASE WHEN row_no = 1 THEN qoh ELSE 0 END) su
                    FROM   Yourtable B
                    WHERE  a.[row_no] >= b.[row_no]) cs
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for..Thanks @Prdp